# virtualbox, cannot ping internal network from host

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have two virtual machines running (mars and saturn):

[image]

**I want them to be able to ping each other**, for this, I set up an internal network adapter on both virtual machines. Here you can see network settings for saturn machine:

[image]

And here you can see network settings for mars machine:

[image]

But for some reason I cannot ping one machine from another, instead I get:
**Reply from ##.##.##.##: Destination host unreachable.** So the questions are:
1) How can I make them see each other?
2) Having two virtual machines on internal network plus how can I made them accessible from host machine?

**UPDATE 2**:
Ok, I now can ping mars from saturn and saturn from mars, but I still can't ping both of them from host.

**Update:**
Here are the ip settings for the mars virtual machine:

[image]

And here are ip settings for saturn virtual machine:

[image]

When I try to ping mars from saturn I get this:

[image]

Here is the output from running **ipconfig /all** on both virtual machines:

[image]

Comment: What OS?
How are the ip settings configured on both machines?

Comment: host machine and both virtual machines are win7,64bit, in virtual machines i didn't change anything, they got their ip automatically

Comment: Run ipconfig/all on both machines and post the output please.

Comment: Ok, I got the answer why I couldn't ping mars from saturn, they both had the same mac address. But I still don't know how to ping both machines from host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [link](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html).

> **Internal networking:**
>
> This can be used to create a different kind of software-based network
> which is visible to selected virtual machines,
> but not to applications running on the host or to the outside world.

The problem you are facing is that the VM's cant reach your DHCP server. It's getting an APIPA adress (169.254.xx.xx)

**Bridged networking**

> This is for more advanced networking needs such as network simulations
> and running servers in a guest. **When enabled, VirtualBox connects to
> one of your installed network cards and exchanges network packets
> directly, circumventing your host operating system's network stack.**

If you have a router or DHCP server on your network, configure this option to receive DHCP packets through the host machines NIC, so the VM's automatically obtain IP adresses.

Else you can configure static ip adresses op both VM's

Example:

```
 VM Mars:  IP 192.168.1.5, Subnetmask 255.255.255.0 
 VM Saturn: IP 192.168.1.6, Subnetmask 255.255.255.0
```

EDIT: If you want the host to communicate with the VM's use a bridged network for the VM's and either give the VM's a static address within the same subnet that your host is in. Or let DHCP assign IP adresses to the VM's dynamicly (to assume your host is getting an DHCP address from the same server/router
)

Answer (score 3):

Two machines with the same hardware address have trouble communicating together, you already figure it out.

You can't ping your VMs from your host by design. Using "[Internal network](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_internal)" allows multiple VMs to communicate together on an internal network but this network is not open to the outside world, including the host.

You might prefer using "[Host-only networking](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly)" which is exactly the same than Internal network but allows the host to join it.

Should you want to access the VMs from other hosts, you might also use [Bridged networking](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged).

Finally, I would advise to configure either fixed IP addresses for your VMs or configure the built-in [VirtualBox dhcp server](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-dhcpserver).